# Trying to loop through a list somehow, skip an element

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops, for-loop, indexing

I am working on a leetcode question. i'm Trying to make sure that each element in list **g** matches with one element of list **s** , where each integer number of list **g** is equal to or less than integer number of list **s**. In the below loop, somehow, it skipped number 2 from list s.

Here is the output:

```
1
1
index0
1
3
index1
2
2
index0
0
```

the source code:

```
g = [1,2]
s = [1,2,3]

count = 0
g = sorted(g)
s = sorted(s)

for x in g:
  for y in s:
    if x <= y:
      print(x)
      print(y)
      index = s.index(y)
      print("index" + str(index))
      del s[index]

print(count)
```

Answer (score 0):

it's generally considered a pretty bad idea to modify either an iterator or a collection being iterated over from within a loop. you delete from the **s** and then try to reference s[1] behind the scenes. (new_s = [2,3] ).
and `y` now ignore the first element that is 2.

but s[1] is now 3, not 2 as you expect, because you have modified the s with `del s[index]`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I was baffled by it. Truly appreciated it.